# extra lines in excel version of the report, SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Hi I have a Reporting service report. I am using grouping on the report. My report looks great in HTML rendering, but in excel version  the first and the last columns are having extra lines, where that  lines are not in html version.

Could anyone please give me a hint , why its so.

Thanks,
Suni

Answer (score 0):

If any controls overlap or are even a single pixel higher or lower in the designer the Excel rendering engine will interpret them as a new row.  Use the property sheet to verify that no controls overlap and that the top and height properties for the controls are identical.

Hope this helps,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a lot when using report headers, where a company logo or report title was much longer than any of the fields of the report, causing merged cells. There is an option you can set in the config of the report server to use simple headers, as well as limit some of the impact of the misaligned cells issue Bill Mueller mentions. Here is a good example of how to achieve this: http://mysqlserverblog.com/2008/01/03/changing-export-options-for-reporting-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this quite a lot, if people tend to export the report a lot i remove all of the formatting from it, limit the number of groups you can drill down into and do as Bill says and make sure you have no overlapping controls.